# OK to use a terminator to manage fixed length arrays?

Tags: c, arrays

I'm working in ANSI C with lots of fixed length arrays.  Rather than setting an array length variable for every array, it seems easier just to add a "NULL" terminator at the end of the array, similar to character strings.  Fot my current app I'm using "999999" which would never occur in the actual arrays.  I can execute loops and determine array lengths just by looking for the terminator.  Is this a common approach? What are the issues with it?  Thanks.

Comment: What's wrong with `sizeof(my_array)/sizeof(my_array_type)`?

Comment: @Ed: `sizeof(my_array) / sizeof(*my_array)` gives you the size (capacity) of the array, not the actual elements used according to the logic of the program.

Comment: If you're using fixed length arrays, then why do you need to terminate them at all?  Terminators are used for variable length strings / arrays.  If they are actually variable length, then @yan has the correct answer below.

Comment: @Mannimarco: "member for 5 months" Don't worry about that. You'll see more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem I can think of is that keeping track of the length can be useful because there are  built in functions in C that take length as a parameter, and you need it to know the length to know where to add the next element too.

In reality it depends on the size of your array, if it is a huge array than you should keep track of the length. Otherwise looping through it to determine the length every time you want to add an element to the end would be very expensive. O(n) instead of the O(1) time you normally get with arrays

Answer (score 2):

This approach is technically used by your `main` arguments, where the last value is a terminal `NULL`, but it's also accompanied by an `argc` that tells you the size.

Using just terminals sounds like it's more prone to mistakes in the future. What's wrong with storing the size along with an array?

Something like:

```
struct fixed_array {
   unsigned long len;
   int arr[];
};
```

This will also be more efficient and less error-prone.

Answer (score 1):

The main problem with this approach is that you can't know the length in advance without looping to the end of the array - and that can affect the performance quite negatively if you only want to determine the length.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just

1. Initialize it with a `const int` that you can use later in the code to check the size, or
2. Use `int len = sizeof(my_array) / sizeof(the_type)`.

Comment: Most of my arrays are two dimensional so size_t length = sizeof(myArray)/sizeof(type) gives me the number of elements in the entire array.  I need the number of elements in each row.  How can that be done?

Comment: @MonkeyBusiness, Add this crucial detail to the question!

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using 2-dimensional arrays to hold a ragged array, you could just use a ragged array: `type *my_array[];`. Or you could put the length in element 0 of each row and treat the rows as 1-indexed arrays. With some evil trickery you could even put the lengths at element -1 of each row![1]

1. Left as exercise ;)